# The Expected Value of $g(X)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, expected-value, absolute-convergence

I am studying "A First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross, and I have come across a problem with the following proof:

**Proposition 4.1**

If $X$ is a discrete random variable that takes on one of the values $x_i$, $i \geq 1$, with respective probabilities $p(x_i)$, then for any real-values function g,
$$E(g(X)) = \sum_i{g(x_i)p(x_i)}$$

**proof**

$$\sum_i{g(x_i)p(x_i)}= \sum_j{\sum_{i:g(x_i)=y_j}{g(x_i)p(x_i)}}=\sum_j{\sum_{i:g(x_i)=y_j}{y_jp(x_i)}}=\sum_j{y_j}\sum_{i:g(x_i)=y_j}{p(x_i)}=\sum_j{y_jP(g(X)=y_j)}=E[g(X)]$$

But we know that we cannot interchange the terms of a conditionally convergent series; we might actually change the sum to another number. I could not prove that the series $\sum_i{g(x_i)p(x_i)}$ is absolutely convergent. So, what allows us to interchange the terms of the series in the first step of the proof?

Comment: I've seen this noted in proofs of this proposition - that absolute convergence IS required.  It's possible the author has glossed over this because in many cases of interest (in particular the examples he shows) are not only discrete, but the space of events is finite.  I'd be interested in others' comments here.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Yes, it makes sense that the author was only considering finite spaces.

Comment: Well at least his examples did. His definition of discrete and proof shown appeared to consider the countably infinite case but did not state this needed assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, in order to appeal to Tonelli or Fubini's theorem to conclude $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}a_{jk} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}a_{jk}$, you need either that $a_{jk} \in [0, \infty]$ for all $j, k$ or that $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}|a_{jk}|< \infty$. Hence his proof works for nonnegative $g$, and therefore the sum is absolutely convergent if and only if $E(|g(X)|) < \infty$ and the theorem holds for such $g$ too.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.